# Is it bad to coalesce the evaluator in a ternary expression? (C#)

Tags: c#, ternary-operator, null-coalescing-operator

I've looked around a little and haven't found an equivalent question.
Is this bad coding practice? I can read it easily, but is it too cryptic for someone reading the code?

```
bool? testBool = null;  
string result;  
result = (testBool ?? false ? "Yes" : "No");
```

**Edit:** My apologies to everyone for some horrible code! Here is a working example..
I'm a little overwhelmed by the speed of the replies. I was going to delete this and do it right, but already had 4 replies!

Comment: I think this code will not compile as testbool is integer

Comment: After your changes it compiles, but IMHO it is not readable

Comment: The choice of placing the parentheses around the whole right-hand side of the assignment is not the best.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'd add parens so clarify what's going on -- ie.

```
bool? testbool = null;
string result;
result = (testbool ?? false) ? "Yes" : "No";
```

With that, I'd be fine with it.  Without it, I had to study it for a bit to figure out what was going on (if it even compiles -- I don't know the order of operations off the top of my head for ?: vs. ??)

Comment: +1 that helps a lot. Original expression is a WTF (in the sense of the "only true measure of code quality - WTF/minute")

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: The original question used an `int?`. It's now been fixed.

That code won't even compile, so yes, I'd say it's too cryptic.

Typos aside, the fact that you posted it without easily *spotting* that there's a problem (you're trying to use a `bool` on the RHS of the ??, when the LHS is an `int?`) suggests it's not a good idea even when you get it right.

I'd need to see a real-world example, but I think I'd *usually* split this into one statement using the null coalescing operator, and then another using the conditional operator. Another *option* is to use the behaviour of nullable types in relation to operators... but again, that's *reasonably* obscure. (I've just had to remind myself exactly what that behaviour is!)

I like the null coalescing operator in general, but I think combining it with the conditional operator just makes it a little bit to obscure. I think I'd probably accept it in a case where there was a significant benefit to it being a single expression (e.g. for initialization where the alternative is introducing an extra method) but in general I'd prefer to split it into two statements.

EDIT: One alternative in *this* particular case is to just compare against "true" - which looks redundant, but isn't in the case of `bool?`:

```
result = (testBool == true) ? "Yes" : "No";
```

The brackets aren't necessary, of course, but add clarity IMO.

I think this is simpler: the result is only "Yes" if `testBool` is actually true; otherwise it's "No". If you wanted to "default" to Yes, you'd write:

```
result = (testBool == false) ? "No" : "Yes";
```

Comment: you're quite right, I'm trying to post an example without actually referencing production code. I'll delete the question once I've made a proper example.

Answer (score 2):

It's a bit on the cryptic side, it's not even obvious if the expression is evaluated as:

```
string result = (testbool ?? false) ? "Yes" : "No";
```

or:

```
string result = testbool ?? (false ? "Yes" : "No");
```

You can use the `GetValueOrDefault` method of the nullable type instead of the `??` operator to make it more readable:

```
bool? testbool = null;
string result = (testbool.GetValueOrDefault(false) ? "Yes" : "No");
```

Answer (score 1):

Wrap it and I think it's fine.

```
string result = (testbool ?? false) ? "Yes" : "No";
```

Otherwise the intended order of operations, even if it works, is not obvious.

(Edit: Jonathan beat me by a pinch.)

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't it be

```
bool? testbool = null;
```

?

I find no need to use a nullable here. This makes me think twice, so I'd really code it as

```
bool testbool = false;
string result;
result = testbool ? "Yes" : "No";
```

I don't know if your example was incomplete, but I think initializing the variable to the default value is saner than using a nullable and then the ?? operator to set the value after the declaration.